# Issue with php code on azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to run the PHP code shown on this page - https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form (scroll down a bit).

This worked fine on my rackspace cloudsite but now that I have moved to azure it doesn't run at all.   I saw some things about curl not being support on azure but it appears to be running and I saw a post in March 2013 it is now supported on azure.

Any idea why that code would not run in Azure Websites?

thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information how you deploy your code to Azure and what kind of error message (or web page) you get as long as you try to run it?

Comment: Is it possible that there's no PHP runtime on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You should first enable PHP Error Output, to get a detailed information about the error. I found this article on google: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/10/16/getting-error-info-for-php-sites-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

If missing curl is the problem, you can install the curl extention this way: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved with information in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/06/12/verify-peer-certificate-from-php-curl-for-azure-apps.aspx

Comment: You should quote relevant information to combat link rot. While MSDN is less likely to disappear than some sites, it's still a good idea. Also, it prevents your answer from simply being a link.